# When I link two header files together, one does not recognize the other

Tags: c++

I'm making a board game using C++ that involves multiple classes. When I include the header file of `piece.h` in `board.h`, all of piece's members are being recognized by the board. But when I simultaneously link `board.h` to `piece.h`, the members of board are not being recognized.
Here are how I am linking them:

-In `piece.h`

```
    #ifndef PIECE_H_
    #define PIECE_H_
    #include <iostream>
    #include "board.h"
```

-In `board.h`

```
    #ifndef BOARD_H_
    #define BOARD_H_
    #include<iostream>
    #include "piece.h"
```

I declared multiple piece members of board and piece type parameters of board functions,  and they work fine.  Yet declaring a void function within piece that takes board parameters, as such:

```
    void horizontal         (Board b);
    void vertical           (Board b);
    void diagonal           (Board b);
```

results in an error saying "Board has not been declared"

Comment: Which one should be compiled first? How will that one know about the other?

Comment: There are many reasons you could have this problem and the snippet you have provided is not it.

Comment: Does `piece.h` really depend on `beard.h`?  Why would a `Piece` object need to know anything about `Board` objects?

Comment: Just a side note, in general without seeing what you are doing, I would assume your piece should not need to include board. When you think about it, a piece shouldn't need to know about the board it is on. The board should contain pieces, and if it needs the piece to do anything specifically it can pass it to the piece as a function parameter, but the piece shouldn't need to know about the board. For instance, if the piece is tracking it's position on the board, it makes more sense for the board to track where the pieces it contains are located.

Comment: In a header file prefer forward declaration to including other header files. In the source file include all the headers you need.

Comment: Sorry... this was my first time posting here and I'm relatively new to programming and this website. I didn't put enough thought into how much detail I should have provided.
To answer your question, RyanP, the pieces need to know characteristics about the pieces interact with such as type and color, so using a char, then get functions seemed a lot less practical than directly interacting with other pieces.

Comment: @Jordan when the board calls functions of pieces, you can have it pass other pieces as a parameter to that function.

Comment: @RyanP For reference I'm making Chess. Basically I have a third function called player, that will name a coordinate on the board. The piece on that coordinate is then called. Each piece has an array of possible moves that is referenced to figure out which moves the player inputs are valid. The contents of this array are determined by assembling all of the valid spaces based off of the characteristics of the pieces on the spaces. So I have players interacting with pieces, which interact with other pieces through the board. So the board is more of a passive tool rather than an implementer.

Answer (score 4):

Including a file basically tells the preprocessor "copy that file's content here". If both headers refer to each other, you have a circular reference, which cannot compile. The compiler has to know at least a bit about the data types being used.
This can be done by using **forward declarations**:

*Board.h*

```
class Piece; // Forward declaration without defining the type

class Board
{
    // Board can makes use of Piece, only as long
    // as it does not need to know too much about it.
    // References and pointers are ok.
    Piece* foo();
    void bar(Piece&);
};
```

*Piece.h*

```
#include "Board.h"

class Piece
{
    // Actual definition of class.
    // At this point Board is fully defined and Piece can make use of it.
    Board* foo() { /*...*/ }
    void bar(Board& x) { /*...*/ }

    // Not only references are possible:
    Board baz(const Board x) { /*...*/ } 
};
```

*Board.cpp*

```
#include "Board.h"
#include "Piece.h"

// Implementation of Board's functions can go after Piece's definition:
Piece* Board::foo() { /*...*/ }
void Board::bar(Piece& x) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Both of your example functions would compile with `A` instead of `A*` and `A&`, by the way ([e.g.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b214ff7f71376171)).

Comment: @chris Your example just forward-declares `bar(Foo)`: Try calling that function from `main()` :-)

Comment: Yes, main needs the definition of `Foo`, which is pretty normal.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help, and sorry for not providing the full MCVE

Answer (score 2):

This include scheme has 2 alternate views.  When piece.h is included, all of the board.h is included before the body of piece.h.

When board.h is included, all piece.h is included before board

To have classes work together

1) you need to predeclare at least one class.
2) To use a class, the compiler either needs to use a reference (or pointer) or know the size.

```
class Board;
```

Then this can be used

```
void horizontal  ( Board & b );
```

Without knowing its size.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this at the top of "piece.h"

```
 class Board;
```

Comment: What does this do? (playing possum, sorry)

Comment: By itself that won't help - at the very least the function prototypes he posted would need to change to take pointers or references.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You mean ["Devils advocate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate) I think.